# Only INADDR_ANY or 0x7f000001 is working how to set any other ip address?

Tags: iphone, ios, sockets, cfnetworking

I am using following code in my App
 but I am getting error when I am setting ip address like **192.168.0.1(in hexadecimal form)** 
 in place of **INADDR_ANY/0x7f000001(127.0.0.1)**.

```
BAction)createSocket:(id)sender {
CFSocketContext CTX = {0, "this is server", NULL, NULL, NULL};
 tcpServer = CFSocketCreate(NULL,0, 0, 0,kCFSocketAcceptCallBack, 0, &CTX);
if (tcpServer == NULL)
    NSLog(@"server isn't created");
else
    NSLog(@"sever is successfully created");
struct sockaddr_in addr;
memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
addr.sin_len = sizeof(addr);
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(2048);
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(0x7f000001); 

NSData *address = [ NSData dataWithBytes: &addr length: sizeof(addr) ];
if (CFSocketSetAddress(tcpServer, (__bridge CFDataRef) address) != kCFSocketSuccess) {
    NSLog(@"socket address not set");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"socket address is successfully added");
}
```

Can I add other ip address or any restriction to use other ip?
If we can than how?

 I would like to use other ip because I am using three iphone to connect each other.

Answer (score 0):

Your local IP address isn't 192.168.0.1. That's your router address. The bind-address has to be an IP address of an NIC in your local host, or INADDR_ANY, or 127.0.0.1.

Comment: So if my all devices have same ip address like 127.0.0.1/INADDR_ANY in this condition can I distinguish the device using only PORT address?